# How the best way to verify if exist a record in database in Django 1.11.x?

Tags: python, django

I want verify if exist a integer number of `order` before save. How I do this?

My Model:

```
class Board(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    curriculum = models.TextField(...)
    order = models.IntegerField(...)
```

[Update 1]

With tip of @DanielRoseman I try do it in `form_valid`.

In my CBV.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    if Board.objects.get(order = form.instance.order):
        # DO SOMETHING
    else:
        return super(BoardCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

My doubt is how to return to the user stating that it already exists

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are facing and what exactly you want to do?

Comment: How I verify if exist and if exist return to user that exist.

Comment: How do you verify if *what* exists? And what is this save method on? The model or the form? Why wouldn't you verify it in validation, anyway?

Comment: I update the question @DanielRoseman, I hope explained it better.

Comment: As I say, this is something you should do in validation - eg in the form's `clean` method.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I understand, the best way is through `form_valid` in my case 'cuz I use CBV. I updated my post.

Comment: raise a validation error, like so: `raise ValidationError('bla bla bla')`

Comment: also don't forget your import : `from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError`

Comment: @scharette, I did but appear debug page, and I need redirect to form save with a INFO message. How I can do it?

Comment: @JulianoAraújo I'm not sure I understand your comment, but if your goal is to only show an info messages and not raise a validation error, take a look at this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/messages/

Answer (score 2):

Try `exists()`

exists() is more faster for checking if an object has been saved in the database.

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have something like:

```
order = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.order:
        print 'Do something'
    super(Board, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: @DanielRoseman said the best way is in `clean` method. I Tried your solution this but not works. Thx.